# How to create a HTML grid of circles that responsively fills the viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid, responsive

My goal is to create a responsive *dot grid*. Following the header, I want to fill the rest of the page with a dot grid that's evenly distributed with evenly proportioned circles.
The ideal result would look like the image below:

[image]

What is the direction to build this grid out, taking into account the *variable* height of the header, and filling the rest of the screen with a grid, with circles that are sized *proportionately* to the viewport width?

The current status of my project is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dot Grid</title>
</head>

<style>
    .header {
        height: 3vw;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .header h2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .dot-grid {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .container-box {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 2px 0;
    }

    .dots-wrapper {
        display: grid;
        position: relative;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-column-gap: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .dots-wrapper .grid-container {
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .grid-container .circle-group {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .dots-wrapper div.grid-container:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .circle-group .circle {
        width: 1.95vw;
        height: 1.95vw;
        border: 1px solid darkgray;
        border-radius: 40px;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 0.1vw;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <h2>Dot Grid Header</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="dot-grid">
        <div class="container-box">
            <div class="dots-wrapper">

                <div class="grid-container">

                    <ul class="circle-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="circle-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="circle-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="circle-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="circle-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="circle-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="circle-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                        <li class="circle"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is your attempt at the JS?

Comment: Your image does not show the dots as evenly placed. Do you want them in groups of three? If so,what are the constraints about the gap between them? Also, do you want just a pattern or do you need each circle to be an element? And do you need a whole number of circles vertically?

Comment: @DanielBlack my attempt at the JS went as far as calculating the height of the dot grid minus the header. `let headerHeight = document.querySelector('.header').offsetHeight;
  let viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
  let heroHeight = viewportHeight - headerHeight;
  let hero = document.querySelector('.dot-grid');
  hero.style.height = `${heroHeight}px`;`

Comment: @AHaworth I need them in groups of three. The gaps between the circles in a group should be no more than 2px. The gaps between the columns should be no more than 10px. Each circle would be an element. There should be a whole number of circles vertically

Comment: Could you describe why each circle needs to be an element?

Comment: @AHaworth I may want to individually style each circle at a later time, for example adding a background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not advise you to do this, but to answer your question directly, here is a simple example of generating adaptive circles according to your requirements:

```js
createCircles();
window.onresize = createCircles;

function createCircles() {
  const columns = 16;
  const cellCircles = 3;

  const circles = document.querySelector('.circles');
  circles.innerHTML = '';
  const cellWidht = circles.offsetWidth / columns;
  const cellHeight = cellWidht / cellCircles;
  const rows = Math.floor(circles.offsetHeight / cellHeight);
  let html = '';
  let cell = '<div class="cell">';
  for (let i = 0; i < cellCircles; i++ ){
    cell += '<i></i>';
  }
  cell += '</div>';
  for (let i = 0; i < columns * rows; i++) {
    html += cell;
  }

  circles.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:  0;
}

body {
  min-height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:auto 1fr;
  padding: 4px;
}

.circles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  min-height: 0;
  grid-gap: 4px 8px;
}

.cell {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.cell i {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="circles"></div>
```

Comment: Im curious, why do you advise against this? Thank You

Comment: Because it creates a lot of elements and can cause performance problems. It is better to do it on `<canvas>`. But, as I understand it, you need the elements

Comment: thank you for outlining that for me, I've accepted your answer!

Comment: would you consider checking this question out, its an extension of this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76543218/15578859