# How to style elements located in the center coordinates of a dynamic CSS Grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I have the following CSS grid layout that contains a fixed number of columns and a  variable number of rows depending on the viewport size. My goal is to superimpose red dots, by styling cells located in the center coordinates of the grid. Like in the image below:

[image]

How would I go about finding the center of the dynamic grid, and calculating the elements that need to be styled so the dots are centered within the grid?

The current status of my project is below:

```js
createCircles();
window.onresize = createCircles;

function createCircles() {
  const columns = 16;
  const cellCircles = 3;

  const circles = document.querySelector('.circles');
  circles.innerHTML = '';
  const cellWidht = circles.offsetWidth / columns;
  const cellHeight = cellWidht / cellCircles;
  const rows = Math.floor(circles.offsetHeight / cellHeight);
  let html = '';
  let cell = '<div class="cell">';
  for (let i = 0; i < cellCircles; i++ ){
    cell += '<i></i>';
  }
  cell += '</div>';
  for (let i = 0; i < columns * rows; i++) {
    html += cell;
  }

  circles.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:  0;
}

body {
  min-height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  padding: 4px;
}

.circles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  min-height: 0;
  grid-gap: 4px 8px;
}

.cell {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.cell i {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles"></div>
```

Comment: Generally speaking to find the center you take the outer width, subtract the child's width and divide by two. (outer - child) / 2. That will give you the left position. Top should be the same.

Comment: @imvain2 Thank you for your response I was able to successfully center the elements. Would you consider looking at my other question related to this dot grid? It involves the spacing between the cells you created. Thanks again for all of your help.